# YII2 Bad Request (#400)

Tags: yii

Народ подскажите как правильно в YII2 при отправке формы НЕ AJAX POST методом передать X-CSRF-Token на сервер?

Или остается только закопать его значение в форму в скрытое поле?

Comment: если делаете форму с помощью ActiveForm то он сам должен в его добавить (в скрытой инпуте)

Comment: да нет ручками форма)

Comment: Возникает вопрос: а зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так на JS:

```
var sendInfo = {
    id_server : ".$model->id.",
    id_app : 1,
    _csrf : yii.getCsrfToken()
};

$.ajax({
    async   : true,
    type     :'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: sendInfo,
    cache    : false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно посмотреть, как он делает это сам через [ActiveFrom](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L282)

```
<?php $request = Yii::$app->getRequest();?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?= $request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= $request->getCsrfToken(); ?>">
```

Comment: капитан очевидность) в вопросе я тот метод указал Или остается только закопать его значение в форму в скрытое поле?
Мне интересно чтоб он в HEADER ушел - вот как это сделать?

Comment: @Ale_x, если под "header" подразумевается способность уйти нативным путем, то только через скрытое поле.

Comment: хочется сделать как реализовано в коробке для AJAX - там токен в заголовки запроса отправляется а не в параметрах .

Comment: @Ale_x, это стандартной формой без js вообще никак не сделать.

Comment: понятно) а как с JS сделать?